# objective-c NSString to 0x%04x format

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *testValue = @"3141";
```

I want to convert "3141" to 0x0c45, use hexadecimal format(0x%04x).
like this:

```
printf("0x%04x", testValue);
```

The value printed out is:

```
0x0c45
```

But I don't know how to save it, how can I do it?

====================================================

```
NSString *testValue = @"3141";
NSUInteger unsignedValue = (NSUInteger)testValue.integerValue;
NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%04X", unsignedValue];
```

The result of this transfer seems to be incorrect. The result is 0x0000. Let me paste the source code as follows:

```
UInt16 myValue = 3141;
printf("0x%04x", myValue);
```

The result printed is 0x0c45. But what I need is not to print, but to save the value 0x0c45.

Comment: `0x0c45` (a numeric value not in double quotes) can be used only as literal.

Comment: Then how do I convert myValue to 0x0c45 and save it.

Comment: Long story short: You can't. Save 3141.

Comment: Can't I save 3141 as 0x0c45?

Comment: Yes, you can't, there is no `hexint16` (or whatever) type. The standard integer types support only the digits `0-9` and the minus sign.

Comment: What if I save as String type?

Comment: Of course string is possible.

Comment: So, how can I save as string type?

Comment: Please read Itai's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [parameters that `printf` expects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters), there's a table of format specifiers that `printf` understands, and the input that `printf` expects to correspond to those format specifiers. Specifically, the `x`/`X` specifiers:

> converts an **unsigned integer** into hexadecimal representation hhhh

When `printf` tries to format `testValue`, it is expecting an unsigned integer of some variety (`unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, etc.), and the `testValue` you pass in is an `NSString *` (a *pointer* to an `NSString`). The pointer value itself is being interpreted as an unsigned integer, and printed out by `printf`.

In order to get `printf` to print the value you actually expect, you will first need to get the integer value of the string (either via [`integerValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410267-integervalue?language=objc), or a different method), and then pass *that* to `printf`. For example:

```objectivec
NSString *testValue = @"3141";
NSUInteger unsignedValue = (NSUInteger)testValue.integerValue;
printf("0x%04X", unsignedValue);
```

(Note that in a production environment, you'll probably want to use something more failure tolerant than just `integerValue`, and you'll need to be aware of the domain of how large `testValue` might need to be, the size of the storage of `unsignedValue`, etc.)

---

**Update:** If you'd like to get the result of formatting a value in this way beyond just printing it, you can use something like [`+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497275-stringwithformat) to get the string value. This method accepts [the same specifiers that `printf` does](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265), so you can use it in the same way:

```objectivec
NSString *testValue = @"3141";
NSUInteger unsignedValue = (NSUInteger)testValue.integerValue;
NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%04X", unsignedValue];

// Do anything you want with `formatted`.
```

Comment: printf just prints, but I want to format this unsignedValue value and save it, how can I do it?

Comment: @Tooodi I've now updated my answer to address that too

Comment: I updated the question, please check.